# Android(4.4+) WebView ignore x-frame-options

Tags: java, android, iframe, webview, x-frame-options

I'm trying to show page with iframes in the app. it shows simple pages, but can't show googlemap iframe.

i've tried: 
hardvre accelleration - turned on (as i know it related only for video),
java script - enabled,
use web chrome client,
loadurl (because of loading from internal memory), ect

the code is:

```
        wewview = new WebView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        wewview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wewview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  
        wewview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wewview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        wewview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            wewview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
        wewview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wewview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND); 

        linearMain.addView(wewview,0);  

        wewview.loadUrl("file://path... /frames.html");
```

could somebody advice how can i switch on "ignore x-frame-options" programmatically for my webview?

**UPDATE 1**

found another message in log

```
05-19 10:01:49.404: I/chromium(4027): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to display 'https://www.google.ru/maps/@?nogmmr=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.", source: about:blank (0)
```

looking for ignore x-frame-options

Comment: is it possible to apply this plugin to webview https://gist.github.com/dergachev/e216b25d9a144914eae2 ?

Comment: or mayby this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25587483/5599807

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the way. there is no full interaction on loaded frame, but i need only to display it. so, Jsoup is used to load page content, but keep loading scripts and images by standatr way, thats all the trick:

```
   private class ignoreXHeaderWebClient extends WebViewClient{  
   private static final String URL_MASK       =  "http";


    //api < 21
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
        WebResourceResponse content = getsPageContent(url);
        if (content != null) {
            return content;
        } else {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }

   // api >= 21
    @Override  
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        WebResourceResponse content = getsPageContent(request.getUrl().toString());
        if (content != null) {
            return content;
        } else {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);  
        }
    }   

    private WebResourceResponse getsPageContent(String url){
        if (( url.contains(URL_MASK)) // guess is better to create for ex map to check all extensions
                && !(( url.contains(".js")) 
                      ||( url.contains(".css"))
                      ||( url.contains(".tiff"))
                      ||( url.contains(".jpg"))
                      ||( url.contains(".png"))
                      ||( url.contains(".gif")))){    
            try {  
                return new WebResourceResponse(
                              "text/html",    
                              "UTF-8",   
                              new ByteArrayInputStream( 
                                   Jsoup.connect(url)
                                           .get()  
                                           .toString()
                                           .getBytes()));  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }   
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

and apply new class:

```
webWiev.setWebViewClient(ignoreXHeaderWebClient);
```